# passing file as prop in react typescript (Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms

I am writing an application with reactjs

I want to upload file which is passed as a prop from child component to parent component

Child Component

```
const RegisterIndividual: React.FC< { upload_id_card: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>} > = ({
  upload_id_card,
  handleInput }) => {

  return (
    <div className="mt-3">

          <input
            type="file"
            name="profile_picture"
            id=""
            onChange=={upload_id_card}
            style={{ display: "block", marginTop: "1rem" }}
          />
     </div>
)};
```

Parent Component

```
const Register = () => {
const upload_id_card = (event) => {
    console.log("type upload file code here")
  }
  return (
    <div className="__register">
    <RegisterIndividual upload_id_card={upload_id_card} />
    </div>
)}
```

but I am getting this error on the child component

```
Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> | undefined'.ts(2322)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `==` and replace with `=`, you want to assign and not compare:

```
onChange=={upload_id_card}
```